# Scipy fitting to function (FOPDT model identification)

Tags: curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, pid-controller

I have data from a doublet test and I'm trying to identify the mathematical model in order to tune a PID controller. This is the plotted data ... I'm pouring hot water (m [kg/s]) into a water tank and displace the colder water inside. [image]

The aim of the fitting is to acquire the values K_p, tau_p, and theta_p.
On APMonitor, there is a [Python script](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/FirstOrderOptimization?action=sourceblock&num=2) available to fit a FOPDT model to data. Sadly, the outcome is very disappointing.  [image]

What could be the reason for this? [This](https://gofile.io/?c=DrpIqo) is the data i used (first column is time, second one the inout, third one the output)

Answer (score 0):

I made a 3D scatterplot of the linked data, and it is not what I expected - but I am unfamiliar with your experimental setup. Please review this plot and the data, the data itself appears to be the problem.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. [At this link](https://filebin.net/461v9vuahskyzowv) you can find the original data from the project and "generated" data which I want to fit a curve to. To me, they do look very similar, however, scipy manages to fit a curve to the original data and not mine.

Comment: Please verify the max and min values for the original and generated data. To me these are very different.

Comment: the scales are very different. i got it working with different initial values ... i guess this can be automized with something like a brute force method, setting different initial values..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was just a problem of wrong initial values. Once I adjusted, I got a much better optimization going. Maybe this can be avoided by choosing the right optimization method?